# Local Firebird Table Editing

Tags: delphi, firebird

My application was coded under Delphi XE5 + Firebird-2.5.6, client / server. ZeosLib.

If I want to edit a record like this:

```
ZTable1.Edit;
ZTable1.FieldValues['champ1'] :=  Edit1.Text;
ZTable1.Post;
```

I wanted to know if this code on the local network, could it have worries or a conflict of editing and post please? That is, editing the table by multiple users will not even have an impact or an error message that pops up at those users. If yes, how to avoid this inconvenience please?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Suppose user A has a record open on the screen, and in the middle of editing it, goes off to lunch.  While A is at lunch, should user B be able to edit the same record and save changes to it?  If so, what should happen when A resumes work? (This is as much about business logic as db transaction handling)

Comment: Seems to me you could figure this out yourself simply by running two copies of your application, no?

Comment: The Edit does not affect the database, only the Post does. The 3 lines will execute very quickly with no delay. Chances of a locking conflict on the Post even with dozens of users is very unlikely. When does the user get a chance to enter values into the Edit1?

Comment: @nolaspeaker:  You should not leave this things to chance.  Do what  happens with TClientDataSet + TDatSetProvider, re-read the record just before the change is applied, then resolve any conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the action with this record that will make the other user and how long your transaction will be active.

For read or after commit or rollback your transaction will be no conflict

Before a transaction end for editing or deleting the record of another user may lock a message or if a user transaction is started with `no_wait` flag, waiting edited transaction completion

P.S. Zeos for Firebird is a very straingth choice. Why you not uses standard IBX library?

Comment: Hello,
The ZConnection component is autocommit. So Zeos handles the transactions. For execution time, hold depends on the user: it can take 10 seconds like it can take 1 minute or more.

I worked with Zeos because I used to work with that.

Comment: @Bill "Autocommit" equals `ExecSQL; Commit`. Between this operation record is locked. Before `Post` server knows nothing about editing record. Run two instances your application and try edit the same record